# Simulating cable length during TDR testing

Tags: cables, tdr

I am trying to create a circuit that can be used as part of a TDR simulator.

What I need to know is if it is possible for the pulse that is sent out by the TDR equipment to be delayed by a piece of circuitry in order to simulate a length of cable. The pulse would then return back to the equipment for analysis.

If anyone has done this before or has any ideas it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What is TDR ? TSR is Terminate Stay Resident... Test Delete, Rebuild?

Comment: A TDR is a time-domain reflectometer. Very common device.

Comment: @mike65535 yes, but given the wide audience on here, abbreviations etc should be explained with the first use, especially as some can have multiple meanings...

Comment: Yes sorry it is Time Domain Reflectometer.